# Solving $\int_0^{\pi/2} \sin^2\theta \sqrt{1-k^2\sin^2 \theta}d\theta $

Tags: integration, elliptic-integrals

I have the following integration to solve.

$$f(k) = \int_0^{\pi/2} \sin^2\theta \sqrt{1-k^2\sin^2 \theta}d\theta,\quad0<k<1$$

assuming $\sin\theta = t$ which results $d\theta = \frac{dt}{\sqrt{1-t^2}}$
and when $\theta = 0, t=0$ and $\theta=\frac{\pi}{2},t=1$
so above equation can be rewritten as,

$$f(k) = \int_0^1{t^2\frac{\sqrt{1-k^2t^2}}{\sqrt{1-t^2}}}dt$$
I'm stuck in solving this further. 
Can somebody help me with some clues/solution to solve this further.

Comment: what is $k$? are there any conditions for $k$?

Comment: $f$ does not depend on $\theta$, so it should be $f(k)$

Comment: @Jane Thanks for your comment. condition for $k$ is $0<k<1$.

Comment: @YuriyS. Corrected. Thanks

Comment: You can see the final solution in terms of elliptic integrals [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+sin(x)%5E2+Sqrt%5B1-k%5E2+sin(x)%5E2%5D+from+x%3D0+to+Pi%2F2)

Comment: Thanks for your reply @YuriyS can you please elaborate. Actually I'm not a mathematics guy. If you can help me to simplify this into elliptical integral form then I can solve it. Thanks.

Comment: I don't actually know how to solve it, but you can use the link I provided to check your own result if you do. I suggest you try integration by parts and/or taking $k^2$ derivative of some known integrals

Comment: Ah thanks. Actually I did not notice the link earlier. I can I think solve it now. Thanks once again.

Comment: There did this integral come from, by the way?

Answer (score 5):

I will use $I(k)$ for the integral instead of $f(k)$.

$$
I(k)=\int^1_0 t^2 \frac{\sqrt{1-k^2 t^2}}{\sqrt{1-t^2}}dt
$$

First, let's find some particular value, we will need it later.

$$I(1)=\frac{1}{3}
$$

Now the definition for the elliptic integral of the second kind:

$$
E(k)=\int^1_0 \frac{\sqrt{1-k^2 t^2}}{\sqrt{1-t^2}}dt
$$

It's easy to show that:

$$
I(k)=E(k)-\int^1_0 \sqrt{1-t^2} \sqrt{1-k^2 t^2} dt
$$

Taking $k$ derivative:

$$
\frac{dI}{dk}=\frac{dE}{dk}+k \int^1_0 t^2 \frac{\sqrt{1- t^2}}{\sqrt{1-k^2t^2}}dt
$$

Now let's use integration by parts for $I(k)$:

$$
I(k)=-k^2 \int^1_0 t^2 \frac{\sqrt{1- t^2}}{\sqrt{1-k^2t^2}}dt+\int^1_0 \sqrt{1-t^2} \sqrt{1-k^2 t^2} dt
$$

Finally we use all three equations to show:

$$
I(k)=-I(k)+E(k)-k\frac{dI}{dk}+k\frac{dE}{dk}
$$

We get a linear ODE for $I(k)$:

$$
\frac{dI}{dk}=-\frac{2}{k} I(k)+\frac{dE}{dk}+\frac{E(k)}{k}
$$

Using the usual method for such equations (reference [here](http://eqworld.ipmnet.ru/en/solutions/ode/ode0103.pdf)) we get the general solution:

$$
I(k)=\frac{C_1}{k^2}+\frac{1}{k^2} \int k^2 \left(\frac{dE}{dk}+\frac{E(k)}{k} \right) dk
$$

To calculate the integral we use the known formula (can be seen [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+k+EllipticE%5Bk%5D)):

$$
\int k E(k) dk=\frac{1}{3} \left[(1+k^2)E(k)-(1-k^2)K(k) \right]
$$

Integrating by parts:

$$
\int k^2 \left(\frac{dE}{dk}+\frac{E(k)}{k} \right) dk=k^2 E(k)-\int k E(k) dk
$$

Finally, the general solution:

$$
I(k)=\frac{C_1}{k^2}+\frac{-(1-2k^2)E(k)+(1-k^2)K(k)}{3k^2}
$$

Now we use the value $I(1)$ we calculated earlier and the known values $E(1)=1$ and $\lim_{k \rightarrow 1} (1-k^2)K(k)=0$ (see [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Limit+(1-x%5E2)EllipticK%5Bx%5D+for+x->1)) to obtain the final solution:

> $$I(k)=\frac{(1-k^2)K(k)-(1-2k^2)E(k)}{3k^2}$$

We can also check the result. From the original integral we can see that:

$$I(0)=\frac{\pi}{4}$$

From the solution (and using series expansions for $E$ and $K$) we get:

$$I(0)=\frac{\pi}{6k^2}(1-k^2+k^2/4-1+2k^2+k^2/4)=\frac{\pi}{4}$$

Answer (score 2):

**Possible hints to perfume some kind of calculations.**

Leaving apart the extrema of the integra, for the moment.

$$\int\sin^2\theta \sqrt{1 - k^2 \sin^2\theta}\ \text{d}\theta$$

Using the substitution

$$k\sin\theta = \cos\phi ~~~~~~~ \sin\theta = \frac{\cos\phi}{k} ~~~ \to ~~~ \sin^2\theta = \frac{\cos^2\phi}{k^2}$$

$$\phi = \arccos(k\sin\theta)$$

$$\text{d}\phi = \frac{- k\cos\theta}{\sqrt{1 - k^2\sin^2\theta}}\ \text{d}\theta = -\frac{k\sqrt{1 - \sin^2\theta}}{\sqrt{1 - \cos^2\phi}}\ \text{d}\theta = -\frac{k\sqrt{1 - \frac{\cos^2\phi}{k^2}}}{\sin^2\phi}\ \ \text{d}\theta$$

Thence $$\text{d}\theta = -\frac{\sin^2\phi}{\sqrt{k^2 - \cos^2\phi}}\ \text{d}\phi$$ and the integral becomes

$$- \int \frac{\sin^2\phi}{\sqrt{k^2 - \cos^2\phi}}\left(\frac{\cos^2\phi}{k^2}\right)\sin^2\phi \text{d}\phi = -\frac{1}{k^2}\int \frac{\sin^4\phi\cos^2\phi}{\sqrt{k^2 - \sin^2\phi}}\ \text{d}\phi$$

Now we can use the trigonometric reduction formula for the numerator of the integrand:

$$\sin^4\phi\cos^2\phi = \frac{1}{32}(2 - \cos(2\phi) - 2\cos(4\phi) + \cos(6\phi))$$

to get

$$ 
-\frac{1}{32k^2}\int\ \frac{2 - \cos(2\phi) - 2\cos(4\phi) + \cos(6\phi)}{\sqrt{k^2 - \sin^2\phi}}\ \text{d}\phi
$$

Which might be splitter into four parts, and then.. who knows!

The solution, however, lies into Jacobi Elliptic Functions of the First an Second Kind.

**More on Jacobi Elliptic Integrals**

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_integral

Comment: You made a mistake when calculating $d \phi$, there should be $-k \cos \theta$ in the numerator, which will complicate the integral

Comment: @YuriyS Thant's it!!! Thank you so much, I'm going to delete/edit the answer! I don't think I will be helpful but who knows.. Upvote for you

Comment: Note, that I made a mistake myself, I edited the comment. Check it again to be sure

Comment: @YuriyS Haha funny! Don't worry, I found my error the same, thanks to your hint!

Answer (score 1):

Following on from @[Yuriy-s](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1644872/solving-int-0-pi-2-sin2-theta-sqrt1-k2-sin2-thetad-theta/1650863#1650863), I have noticed that the integral:

$$\int k E(k) dk=\frac{1}{3} \left[(1+k^2)E(k)-(1-k^2)K(k) \right]$$

Is incorrect according to wolfram alpha. @Yuriy-s has used [this](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate%20k%20EllipticE%5Bk%5D) to evaluate the expression, but note that wolfram alpha read this as:

$$\int k E(k^2) dk$$

Making a correction to this gives me [this](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate%20a%20EllipticE%5Ba%5D):

$$\int k E(k) dk=\frac{2}{45} \left[3k^2 + k-4)K(k)+(9k^2+k+4)E(k) \right] + C_2$$

where $C_2$ is a constant.

The following @Yuriy-s and subbing in various things:

$$I(k)=\frac{C_1}{k^2}+\frac{1}{k^2} \int k^2 \left(\frac{dE}{dk}+\frac{E(k)}{k} \right) dk$$

$$I(k)=\frac{C_1}{k^2}+E(k) - \frac{2}{45k^2} [(3k^2 +k -4) K(k) +(9k^2 +k +4)E(k)]  + C_2$$

But there is a problem.

putting in the boundary conditions of:
$$I(0)=\frac{\pi}{4}$$

[$$E(0)=\frac{\pi}{2}$$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=EllipticE%5B0%5D)
[$$K(0)=\frac{\pi}{2}$$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=EllipticK%5B0%5D)

Gives us:
$$\frac{\pi}{4} = \frac{C_1}{0}+\frac{\pi}{2} - \frac{2}{0} [-4\frac{\pi}{2} +4\frac{\pi}{2}] +C_2 $$

$$C_2=\frac{-\pi}{4}$$
$$C_1=0$$

for a final result of:
$$I(k)=E(k) - \frac{2}{45k^2} [(3k^2 +k -4) K(k) +(9k^2 +k +4)E(k)]  - \frac{\pi}{4}$$

Unfortunately this is not the same as wolframs' final [answer](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+sin(x)%5E2+Sqrt%5B1-k%5E2*sin(x)%5E2%5D+from+x%3D0+to+Pi%2F2) though:

$$I(k)=\frac{ \sqrt{1-k^2} [K(\frac{k^2}{k^2-1})  + (2k^2-1)E(\frac{k^2}{k^2-1}) ]}{3k^2}$$

Comment: There are two typical conventions for elliptic integrals: Taking them to be functions of $k$, or as functions of $m=k^2$. Mathematica, and therefore Wolfram Alpha, uses the latter; the answer by Yuriy-s, by contrast, uses the former convention. That'd be my guess for why there's a seeming discrepancy.

Comment: @Semiclassical-19 That seems plausible.
But then why does wolfram give different results depending on whether you input the k varaible as any other symbol?
http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+a+EllipticE%5Ba%5D
http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+k+EllipticE%5Bk%5D

Answer (score 0):

No I find a problem with the last formula: with MAPLE the real part is false but the  imaginary part is right.
A true formula is according to WOLFRAM is [(1-k^2)*K(k^2)+(2*k^2-1)*E(k^2)]/3*k^2.