# Assistance with solving the integral

Tags: calculus, integration, analysis, elliptic-integrals

Can you give me an idea how to handle this integral?

$\int_{0}^{2\pi} (1+\cos{x})\sqrt{3+\cos{x}}\,dx$

Comment: What have you tried so far? We can help you better, when you tell us, how you approached this question, what ideas you had and what steps you did not understand.

Comment: I tried to use the substitution $u=\tan{x}$ and $\tan{\frac{x}{2}}=u$. Also, I tried to transform this expression to an expression with $\sin^2{\frac{x}{2}}$, as well as to halve the interval, but that lead me to nowhere near the solution. I'm really looking for hits here.

Comment: I would try to replace $1+\cos x$ by $2\cos^2(x/2)$,  $\sqrt{3+\cos x}$ by $\sqrt{2}\sqrt{1+\cos^2(x/2)}$ and use the power series $(1+h)^{1/2} = \sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} {1/2 \choose n} h^n$ for $h \in [-1,1]$, which is normally convergent on $[-1,1]$.

Comment: Kindly edit the post with your attempt. This post can be reopened (or closure can be prevented) after doing that. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Since $1 - \cos(x) = 2 \sin^2\left(\frac{x}{2} \right) $ then
\begin{align}
\int_{0}^{2\pi} (1+\cos{x})\sqrt{3+\cos{x}}\, \mathrm{d}x & \overset{u= x -\pi}{=} 2\int_{0}^{\pi}2 \sin^2\left(\frac{u}{2} \right) \sqrt{2+2\sin^2\left(\frac{u}{2} \right)}\, \mathrm{d}u \\
& \overset{t = \frac{u}{2}}{=} 8 \sqrt{2} \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \sin^2(t) \sqrt{1 + \sin^2(t)}\, \mathrm{d}t\\
\end{align}
And from [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1650863/695196) we know
$$
\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \sin^2\theta \sqrt{1-k^2\sin^2 \theta}\, \mathrm{d}\theta = \frac{(1-k^2)K(k)-(1-2k^2)E(k)}{3k^2}
$$
So with $k=i$ you get
$$
\int_{0}^{2\pi} (1+\cos{x})\sqrt{3+\cos{x}}\, \mathrm{d}x  =8 \sqrt{2} E(i) - \frac{16 \sqrt{2}}{3} K(i)
$$

Comment: It is amazing to see how many expressions we can obtain for the definite integral

Answer (score 3):

Using the tangent half-angle substitution
$$I=\int_{0}^{2\pi} (1+\cos(x))\sqrt{3+\cos(x)}\,dx=2\int_{0}^{\pi} (1+\cos(x))\sqrt{3+\cos(x)}\,dx$$
$$I=8 \sqrt{2} \int_0^\infty \sqrt{\frac{t^2+2}{\left(t^2+1\right)^5}}\,dt=4 \sqrt{2}\int_1^\infty \frac 1 {x^2}\sqrt{\frac{x+1}{(x-1) x}}$$ The antiderivative is  [nasty](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=Integrate%5BSqrt%5B%282+%2B+t%5E2%29%2F%281+%2B+t%5E2%29%5E5%5D%2Ct%5D) but its evaluation at $\infty$ is simply
$$I=\frac{2 }{3 \sqrt{\pi }}\left(\Gamma \left(\frac{1}{4}\right)^2+12\, \Gamma
   \left(\frac{3}{4}\right)^2\right)$$ which is the same as
$$I=16  \left(E\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)-\frac{1}{3}K\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)\right)$$ and
$$I=8 \sqrt{2} \left(E(-1)-\frac{2 }{3}K(-1)\right)$$ already given by @Robert Lee.